# How do I setnumber and relativenumber for :Explore in .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, line-numbers

In my `.vimrc` I have `set relativenumber` and `set number` it works in the editor but not in `:Explore`. I have to set it manually every time.

How can I always get `set relativenumber` and `set number` in `:Explore`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set it in `g:netrw_bufsettings`.  The default is `"noma nomod nonu nobl nowrap ro nornu"`, so this should do:

```
let g:netrw_bufsettings = "noma nomod nu nobl nowrap ro rnu"
```